# Representation for increasing function on unit square

Tags: special-functions, approximation-theory

Do you know any result concerning the representation of functions $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ continuous and increasing (with $f(0)=0,f(1)=1)$) as convex combinations of a family of particular functions?

If we denote by $\mathcal{K}$ the family of functions like above the question is if there exists a family $\mathcal{B}$ (strictly smaller than $\mathcal{K}$) of functions as above such that each $f \in \mathcal{K}$ can be written as
$$ \sum_{i \in I}\alpha_i b_i \text{ with } b_i \in \mathcal{B} \text{ and } \sum_{i\in I}\alpha_i=1 (\alpha_i>0) $$

---

I think a related question is the following:

If we denote by $M=\{f:[0,1] \to [0,1]: f(x)= x^\lambda ,  \lambda > 0\}$ then what is the convex hull of $M$? Is it close to the family $\mathcal{K}$ above? I guess it cannot be equal, since curves which simultaneously have low slope around zero and low slopes around one are not in $M$.

---

If we view $\mathcal{K}$ as a subset of $C([0,1])$ we can easily see that it is convex. Is there any way we can impose some restrictions on $\mathcal{K}$ ($C^1$ with bounded derivatives, Lipschitz, etc) so that the resulting set is still convex and has reasonable extremal points (in order to use Krein Milman theorem)?

Comment: (i) you also want $\alpha_i\ge 0$; (ii) such functions $f$ are in one-to-one correspondence with atomless probability measures on $[0,1]$. The measures can be neatly approximated by a *sequence of convex combinations* of normalized Lebesgue measure restricted to dyadic intervals. But representing as a *sum* is harder. For one thing, to represent singular measures one needs the building blocks to also be singular measures, so they can't be much simpler that the measure we are representing.

Comment: Yes, indeed, $\alpha_i \geq 0$.

Comment: Note that for any $a\in {\mathcal K}$ there are $x,y\in {\mathcal K}$ with $x \lt a \lt y$ on $]0,1[$. So the convex set $\mathcal K$ does not have any extremal points.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: good point.

Comment: @BeniBogosel also, my hunch is that the absence of extremal points will hold for any reasonable subspace of the space of increasing homeomorphisms (for example, it holds for the space of ${\mathcal C}^{\infty}$ diffeomorphisms), so that your project is essentially doomed.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: That was also my feeling about this problem, but I thought: why not ask it to see what others have to say... Maybe I've missed something important.

Answer (score 2):

The subset of piecewise linear functions is such a subset. Take an increasing piece wise linear function $f$ that fixes 0 and 1 such that $1/2 f$ stays within 1/2 of the function while remaining below it (such as being 0 until the function is close to 1/2, then rising to 1/2 until the end). Then take another piece wise linear function $g$ such that $1/4 g+1/2 f$ stays within 1/4 of the function, while still remaining below it. Continuing in this way, we get the original function as a convex combination of piece wise linear functions.

A certain subset of increasing piece wise linear functions fixing the end points is called Thompson's group.

**Edit** As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't work. This construction works for $C^1$ functions, and possibly Lipschitz or absolutely continuous functions.

Comment: This brings up some excellent questions: (1) What is the convex hull of Thompson's group $F$?  Is it precisely the set of all increasing, piecewise-linear homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$?  (2) Is there a reasonable function space for which $F$ is precisely the set of extremal points of the closure of this convex hull?

Comment: It can't be, I think, because of functions which have non-zero slope at the origin, since every element of Thompson's group has nonzero slope there (I believe).

Comment: I don't think this works. After you subtract $(1/2)f$ from the given function, the result may fail to be increasing, in which case it cannot be given as a convex combination of increasing functions. For example, the Cantor staircase is not a convex combination of increasing PL functions.

Comment: I think $C^1$ is as far as it goes. As I noted in a comment on the question, it is equivalent to representing the distributional derivative of $f$ as a convex combination of derivatives. You need continuity to write a function in terms of piecewise constant ones.